# solve for $p$ in $aJe^Tp1=pe1$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Given the expression $aJe^Tp1=pe1$, is there a matrix solution for $p$ ? There should be an infinite number of solutions, as I've already solved it without matrices for n=3. But I dont know if there is a more succinct way using matrices. The solution I have works when I evaluate the expression $aJe^Tp1=pe1$ numerically.

${a}$ is an nxn diagonal matrix where all $0 \lt a_{ii} \lt 1 $ and $\sum a_{ii} =1 $

$p$ is an nxn diagonal matrix where all $ p_{ii} \gt 0 $

$e$ is an nxn matrix where all $ e_{ij} \ge 0 $

$J$ is an nxn matrix of 1s

$1$ is a nx1 column vector of 1s

I don't know much algebra, but I know enough (I think) to know that I can't get rid of the $1$ vectors since they don't have an inverse, and multiplying by $1^T$ won't do much good because $J$ is not invertible either. So I am quite confused. And it is not that important, but I am curious about it.

Comment: You might want to repeat the title in the question, it is not terribly readable.

Answer (score 1):

Use uppercase/lowercase for matrix/vector variables to write the problem as
$$\eqalign{
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\diag{\operatorname{diag}}
\def\Diag{\operatorname{Diag}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
&PEJ = AJE^TPJ \\
&P = \Diag(p),\quad A &= \Diag(a),\quad I &= \Diag(\o),\quad J=\o\o^T \\
&p = \diag(P),\quad a &= \diag(A),\quad \o &= \diag(I),\quad J=J^T  \\
}$$
This identity involving the Hadamard product $(\odot)$
$$\eqalign{
\diag(R\cdot\Diag(p)\cdot Q) = (Q^T\odot R)\cdot p \\
}$$
allows the problem to be written as a standard matrix-vector equation
$$\eqalign{
(JE^T\odot I)\,p &= (J\odot AJE^T)\,p \;=\; (AJE^T)\,p \\
(\c{AJE^T-JE^T\odot I})\,p &= \c{M}p \;=\; 0 \\
}$$
So the vector $p$ must lie in the nullspace of $M$, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
p &= (I-M^+M)w \\
}$$
where $M^+$ is the pseudoinverse and $w$ is an arbitrary vector.

This solution is not unique, but the constraint $\sum_kp_k={\tt1}$ yields a unique solution.